# Components, dynamicly creation and work with them

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have to develop Windows C# application, using Visual Studio 2008. It have dynamical to create pictureboxes, to add image in it, and to move picturebox to some X position.

So, I have windows form with next components:

1. button, with title "Add new"
2. Combobox
3. Text Field
4. another button, with title "Set position".

Also, I have one folder with several images (png files) in it.

So, when I click on first button it have to create new PictureBox, and to add name of Picturebox into ComboBox.

After that, I can choose one PictureBox from it's list in combobox, and to move it to X position I entered into TextBox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DynamicComponents
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int imgCounter = 0;


        /*
         * Create pictureboxes and add images
         */ 
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.Name = "PictureBox" + (++imgCounter);
            pb.Size = new Size(100, 100);
            pb.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\slike\" + imgCounter.ToString() + ".png");
            this.Controls.Add(pb);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(pb.Name);
        }


        /*
         * Move PictureBox on X position I entered into textfield
         * */
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // help!!!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Smells like homework. Let us know if this is homework, it means you'll get fuller explainations, it doesn't mean that you wont get help.

Comment: It's not homework, it's part of solution I have to develop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already (successfully it seems) managed to dynamically create new `PictureBox` controls, add them to the form and also show their name in the `ComboBox`.

When you click the button, you will somehow need to "navigate" from the selected item in the `ComboBox` to a `PictureBox`. One simple way of achieving this is to use the fact that the list in a `ComboBox` takes any object, not only strings. So, instead of adding `pb.Name` to the `ComboBox`, you can add `pb` itself. This will create one small problem though; instead of the name of the picture box, the combo box will now show `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox`. This can be fixed by setting the [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) property of the `ComboBox` (this property tells the `ComboBox` which property value to fetch from each object and use for display):

So, you could set the `DisplayMember` property in the constructor of `Form1`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"; // use the Name property from items 
                                      // in the list when displaying them
}
```

Then, when creating the `PictureBox` controls, add them to the `ComboBox`:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(pb);
```

Now you can easily pick up the `PictureBox` reference from the `ComboBox` in `button2_Click`:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox selectedPictureBox = comboBox1.SelectedItem as PictureBox;
    if (selectedPictureBox != null)
    {
         // use selectedPictureBox to set the appropriate property values
    }
}
```

Comment: Great!!!! Thank you on quick solution!!!
:-)

Now, just one more question... I will use this code form application that will make some sort of loop with it, where about 50 PictureBoxes will be dynamically created, and also moved around and around all over the form.

If I use code like this, it is safe regarding memory use?

Hope that you understand my question...

Tnx in adv!!!

Comment: @unknown: Yes, that should be safe. Note though that if you *unload* `PictureBox` controls you should call `Dispose` on the images (through the `Image` property) and on the controls in order to release resources.

Comment: Just one more question!

Everything is the same, except...

What will be if I set one string variable, like

string workingItem = "PictureBox2";


And no mether which one is selected in combobox, always will be moved picurebox with name PictureBox2. Of course, if it exist.


So, I have to work with string value, not with selected item from Combo.


Thank you again, in advance!